# How to scroll long sub-menu in WordPress through CSS or using any plugins

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How to Scroll long sub-menu in WordPress through css or using any plugins? I have a website it has long sub-menu. I tried with CSS but its not working properly on hover.

I have tried two css to handle it but not got desire result for example. Please check the website for the second menu which is large http://www.nitai.in

```
.sub-menu {
  max-height:700px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

or

```
ul ul {
 max-height: 700px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have overflow visible on hover which you need to delete from the code.

```
nav.main-menu-wrap ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
        overflow: visible; // <- delete this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CSS code. It's working

```
.sub-menu {
    height: 500px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

or

```
nav.main-menu-wrap ul li ul.sub-menu{
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```